# What is the best way to make my desktop look like a mac?

Tags: 10.10, mac

I heard something about Macubuntu and want to try.

Is there anyone using macubuntu and what do you think about it? :)

Comment: Are you more interested in cosmetic changes (theme, wallpaper, etc.) or functional changes (dock, expose, etc.)? Or both?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download this all in one Package [Macbuntu](http://sourceforge.net/projects/macbuntu/) and read more about it on this [Webupd8 Article](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/make-ubuntu-look-like-mac-osx-in.html)

Comment: Glad to be of help :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found this amazing tutorial on 5 steps to transform your Ubuntu to Mac
[OMGUbuntu - 5 Tips To transform Ubuntu To MAC](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/08/omg-5-five-tips-hacks-and-tweaks-)

Then , I found a nice splash screen/boot screen to make Ubuntu feels more like Mac . Its a splash screen theme from plymouth . Enjoy =) [UbuntuRoot - Plymouth Mac OS X Splash Screen](http://www.ubunturoot.com/2010/08/paw-ubuntu-and-os-x-like-plymouth-theme.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could try Mac4Lin, it's a good transformation tool. http://sourceforge.net/projects/mac4lin/
Instructions http://www.howtoforge.com/mac4lin_make_linux_look_like_a_mac

Answer (score 0):

A couple of ideas:

Docky will give you a (vaguely) OSX-like Dock. You can install it via Software Centre (in 10.10 at least). You can then remove your bottom panel and launch Docky.

You can get the menus-in-top-bar thing of OSX by right-clicking in the top panel, clicking "add to panel", then adding "Indicator Applet Appmenu". You can then delete the Main Menu from the left-hand side of the top panel, and move the Application Menus to the left-hand side.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that Indicator Applet Appmenu is quite unstable as of now. (It'll freeze your machine if you use it whilst a new application is opening) I would suggest you look into Gnome GlobalMenu instead.